# How can I check if an object is a Rectangle or an Ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles, ellipse

How can I check if the object that is created a Rectangle or an Ellipse is in WPF?

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(); 

if (rect.getType()){
    rect.Margin = new Thickness(x,y,0,0);
} else {
    ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Margin is a property of FrameworkElement, which is a base class of both Ellipse and Rectangle. You don't need code like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `is` [keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) you can check which type an object is.

```
if(rect is Rectangle)
```